# general question to built responsive website

Tags: css, media-queries

I am learning webdesign(wordpress) so I come in problem with media queries.
I use Bootstrap 4 grid system so I am using also media queries of bootstrap 4
which is :

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

I see these media queries are not enough, especially with iPhones and Samsungs new series.
I see that I have to write extra breakpoints to target those mobiles.
I made a search in google and I see another kind of media queries which is targeting width and height with `webkit-device-pixel-ratio:2` or 3 etc. I see also there is also a device targeting media queries which makes me confused.
my question is now:
if I use extra breakpoints for 375 width 4014 width iPhones etc will be enough or I have also to target height and `webkit-device-pixel ratio`.
What do you advise me? There are a lot of mobile devices with different resolutions.

Comment: In media Query, I think you have to focus on Galaxy S5 First, because it is showing the same view for MotoG, IPhone 6/7/8 and plus, Pixel X2 as well. For IPad you can use 768 - 1024 and for Ipad Pro and laptop 1024 - 1600 / 2000 and for extra large device 2000 or more. I am working by using this and its working for me everytime thats why i am you same advice as i am using. You can check and then let me know if its working for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

thanks,
I did with this code:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
    
    .site-header  {
        background-color:brown;
    }
    
}
```

but when I open in chrome inspect elements I see it is only targetting Galaxys5 and Moto G4.not iphone or Pixel2.
you can see yourself on: http://webdesignleren.com/
thanks